# Refocusing app to foreground restarts entire app

Tags: android, android-intent

I was wondering if anyone knows anything about this problem - I have created an app and i'm just testing it, and the problem is that every time i put the app in to the background or minimise it, when i bring it to the foreground again the entire application restarts from the first activity intent.
Is there a way around this? I can't help but feel i'm missing some fundamental knowledge here?

```
My MainActivity is shown below:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout_main);
        actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent); 


}
```

so as you can see the savedInstanceState is being called on the onCreate.

Comment: How are you closing the app and how do you bring it to foreground again?

Comment: im using Genymotions back button (the backward facing arrow), to go back to the desktop (not sure if thats the right term for phones) and then clicking the two screens on top of one another (presumably some form of app handling list) to bring the app to the foreground again. The version of Android is API17 and its on a Galaxy Samsung S3 emulator.

Comment: If you use the home button to put your app in the background, it should resume where it left off, assuming the OS doesn't kill your app due to lack of memory.  Post your onCreate() methods.  Are you remembering to call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ?  Android uses this saved information to recreate the activity.  If you use the back button to go back to the home screen, it should resume on your Main_Activity.

Comment: Try pressing the home button to close the app and tell me if it works then,

Comment: Do you add any flags to your intents? If so, which flags?

Comment: I think the problem is i'm getting confused as to the functions of the buttons in the Genymotion emulator. I tried pressing the home button and then reloading the app from the application list and it starts the application where it left off. It must have been the back arrow closing the app down :/
Thank you all for your time, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button will by default completely close your app. You will either have to press the home button instead or add custom logic to `onBackPressed()` in order to circumvent this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Set in the manifest.xml file:

in Activity:

```
"android:clearTaskOnLaunch" to false.
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to make any difference, it's still restarting the entire app